# XLS files on website

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an XLS file, such as www.mysite.com/test1.xls. When clicking on the link it always brings up the spreadsheet inside Internet Explorer, with excel embedded in the browser and in a less functional version. For instance, panes and auto-filtering in the document do not work.

Can I force this to open directly in full excel, for all users, no matter their browser? Perhaps some additional tag I can put on the link?

Btw, Word documents behave the same way, but the issue is mostly with excel.

Comment: There is an answer here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to create a download link

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/test1.xls" target="_blank">FILE</a>
```

When you `target="_blank"` you tell the browser to open a new window which *should* **prompt the user to decide** to download or open the file.

```
_blank  Opens the linked document in a new window or tab
_self   Opens the linked document in the same frame as it was clicked (this is default)
_parent Opens the linked document in the parent frame
_top    Opens the linked document in the full body of the window
framename   Opens the linked document in a named frame
```

[more information](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: The target option makes it open in a new window or tab, but it is still embedded in the browser.

Comment: It needs to work for everybody else but me, since I already have the file on my own harddisk. I am the one uploading it in the first place.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard I understand. What I'm saying is that the browser on your machine might have a setting that automatically opens the file a specific way. Try to reset the settings on the browser to see if it prompts you on what you'd like to do

Answer (score 0):

If your Web Server is apache, all you need to do is add on your .htaccess config the following lines:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .xls
AddType application/octet-stream .doc
AddType application/octet-stream .xlsx
AddType application/octet-stream .docx
```

If your web server is ISS, on your web.config

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".xls" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlxs" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".doc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".docx" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```